# making POST request using fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch, axios

If not using vanilla js I have always used jQuery to make `AJAX` requests. Now since React has been taking over, to make `AJAX` requests there is no need to use the whole `jQuery` library to make these requests so we are encouraged to use either js' built in `fetch` method, axios or many others.

I have been trying to make a `POST` request using `fetch`. I am able to make it using `axis` but not fetch.

```
axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/login', {
    "email": "peter@klaven",
    "password": "cityslicka"
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The axios code looks like this, but when I try what I believe to be the same thing using `fetch` it doesn't work. Can anyone see what I am missing? The values are being posted, but the API is returning an error, so I must be doing something wrong.

```
var data = {
    "email": "peter@klaven",
    "password": "cityslicka"
}

fetch("https://reqres.in/api/login", {
    method: "POST",
    body:  JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(function(response){ 
    return response.json(); 
})
.then(function(data){ 
    console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the API wants a JSON body, not URL-encoded like normal form posts?

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? Is the request not happening? Is it failing to get the values across?

Comment: @Osman  I have updated the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 var headers = {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",                                                                                                
   "Access-Control-Origin": "*"
}
```

try adding  the above  lines to headers.

```
var data = {
    "email": "peter@klaven",
    "password": "cityslicka"
}

fetch("https://reqres.in/api/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body:  JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(function(response){ 
    return response.json(); 
})
.then(function(data){ 
    console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: would you mind explaining why the `headers` needed to be added?

Comment: Only the `Content-type` header is required, because it provides the client with the actual content type of the returned content. If the response object is going to be in json format, then that header is mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
fetch('http://myapi.com/user/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      login: login,
      senha: password
    })
  }).then(response => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => console.log(responseJson))
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Change the URL string to single quotes **'** instead of **`**